# Import non-standard python module in Jython

Tags: python, class, jython

A quick question... I'm using Jython to do some tasks, and I need to access some MySQL Databases... I've found a MySQL Database Connector for Python2.5; it doesn't come with the jython/python installation (it's 3rd party). I've placed the module's folder in the same directory as my main.py, but when I launch it, it tells me that it can't find the module. I've done this before in Python3.2 for importing and I thought it would work the same.

**Can Jython import non-standard python modules? -- Note I can import Java classes just fine.**

Here is the Error (Yes, this is for Minecraft):

```
20:50:44 [SEVERE] org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<iostream>", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyDbLite

20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.lahwran.bukkit.jython.PythonPluginLoader.loadPlugin(PythonPluginLoader.java:280)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.lahwran.bukkit.jython.PythonPluginLoader.loadPlugin(PythonPluginLoader.java:113)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.lahwran.bukkit.jython.PythonPluginLoader.loadPlugin(PythonPluginLoader.java:83)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:305)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at com.master.bukkit.python.PythonLoader.onLoad(PythonLoader.java:58)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:212)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:183)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.ServerConfigurationManager.<init>(ServerConfigurationManager.java:53)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.init(MinecraftServer.java:156)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:422)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:492)
20:50:44 [SEVERE] Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<iostream>", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyDbLite

20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.PyException.fillInStackTrace(PyException.java:70)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:29)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:32)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:46)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:43)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:61)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:290)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:750)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:834)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:884)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.imp.importOne(imp.java:903)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.pycode._pyx5.f$0(<iostream>:52)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.pycode._pyx5.call_function(<iostream>)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1261)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:235)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:230)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   at net.lahwran.bukkit.jython.PythonPluginLoader.loadPlugin(PythonPluginLoader.java:239)
20:50:44 [SEVERE]   ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using jython, use the [mysql connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html) jar. Download it, add it to your `CLASSPATH`, and make sure your user executing the code has read permissions to the location where the jar is.

Once you have the jar, follow [the documentation](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html) for sample code.

Comment: So is there no way to import a non-standard library?

Comment: Typically you can use most modules, but database connectors are generally compiled against the libraries for the implementation - which is why it is recommended to use the native libraries.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you! Will using the Java version be much different?

Answer (score 4):

jython can import non-standard python modules if they are pure python.  database connections are typically cpython modules.  For database connectivity, see [zxJDBC](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/DatabasesAndJython.html)  It makes any jdbc connectivity available to java behave in the standard python DBI 2.0  kind of way.

Best of both worlds!

Answer (score 3):

PyDbLite is ostensibly pure-python, so it should import into jython OK.  I've not tried to use a setup.py with Jython, but I've imported several pure-python .py's that didn't ship with Jython, from Jython.  I have one project that runs on CPython 2.x, CPython 3.x, Pypy and Jython using the usual import machinery.

The main question that comes to mind is: Is PyDbLite in a directory on your sys.path?

Comment: It is in the Directory user1277476. The same directory that the script is located in.