# How to import a non-native Java package to Jython?

Tags: java, python, import

I am working on porting some code from Java to Python using Jython. The Java code contains imports such as these.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
```

How can I import these using Jython? I've tried making a database, using the postgresql jdbc, but I have no idea how to use that, I've also looked everywhere, and at questions [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340453/import-non-standard-python-module-in-jython), but I can't find out how to do it. I've also looked at zxJDBC, documentation, however, whenever trying to connect using zxJDBC, I get an error that says this:

```
zxJDBC.DatabaseError: driver [org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver] not found
```

EDIT: The project also contains a `pom.xml` file, does this have anything to do with the imports?